# am not able to configure readTimeout to be more than 60 sec in karate

Tags: karate

One of my api's take more than 2 mins ( i know it's bad response time) to respond and am using karate to test it. I tried to increase the default 30 sec time by  * configure readTimeout = 90000 but it still only waits for 60 sec. am using karate v 0.7.0. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try switching to `karate-jersey` from `karate-apache` or vice-versa. Also try the other `connectTimeout` setting. Else, upgrade to 0.9.1, in case this bug-fix is involved: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/586

Comment: Tried all of the above and nothing worked. I can only wait for a max of 60 sec. Looks like a bug.

Comment: @Kumar112 no one else has reported this. please help us debug or replicate this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Well, it might well a problem with the app server. Postman also timeout exactly after 60 sec even though i increased the timeout. I will work with systems engineer to confirm it's an issue.

Comment: this is not a bug.

Comment: @Kumar112, this is happening for me too. Works in Postman, but fails in Jenkins

Comment: @cosbor11 most likely you have an HTTP proxy involved: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+postman+proxy